# Make Batch file try Drives D/E/F/H and have it copy from G to them

Tags: batch-file, usb, xcopy, drive

```
@echo on
set choice=
:D
if exist D: (set choice=D:) if exist (choice=D:) goto copyG else goto E
:E
if exist E: (set choice=E:) if exist (choice=E:) goto copyG else goto F
:F
if exist F: (set choice=F:) if exist (choice=F:) goto copyG else goto H
:H
if exist H: (set choice=H:) if exist (choice=H:) goto copyG 
:copyG
xcopy /e /y G:\2019-Year10\*.* "%choice%"
pause
:removed
echo removed
```

This is my current code.
But is does not copy the files to the USB from the G drive.

Is there a way to fix this?

Edit:

Thanks got it working in the end i used this

```
@echo off

echo.
echo Finding Drive to copy work from "G:\2019-Year10"

echo.
for %%i in (D: E: F: H:) do (
    if exist %%i set drive=%%i
)
xcopy /e /y "G:\2019-Year10\*.*"  "%drive%\2019-Year10\"

echo.
echo Files coped to "%drive%"

echo.
echo.
echo Remove %drive% Drive

:removle_of_drive
if exist %drive% (goto removle_of_drive) else exit
```

It knows when you take out the USB and closes the batch file, and gives you more info on what it is doing
thanks for the help: Gerhard Barnard

Comment: I don't get it.. Do you want to copy from your USB?

Comment: i am trying to copy to the use but sometimes the driver is difrent on some pc so i need it to be able to copy it to Driver E/F/D/H

Comment: why not attempt to detect where USB is plugged in?

Comment: im new to coding in batch how do i do this

Comment: See answer below, top script is more automated where bottom is a fixed version of your code.

Comment: There are several issues in your code: 1. what would happen if none of the drives was available? 2. what is `if exist (choice=D:)` supposed to do? 3. there is no need to explicitly `goto` the next line. 4. when using `if`/`else` you need parantheses: `if <condition> (<true_command(s)>) else <false_command(s)>`. And something general about your approach: 1. can you be sure the USB stick is not mapped to other drive letters? 2. can you really exclude that other devices are mapped to one of the proposed drive letters?

Comment: I can see you didn't read the help file for the `IF` command.  The syntax your are using isn't remotely close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here we can use `wmic` to determine the disk type. *Note!!!* If you have more than one USB attached, this will not do as intended:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-4" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^,description^,drivetype 2^>nul') do (
       if %%l equ 2 (
          echo xcopy /e /y "G:\2019-Year10\*.*" "%%d"
     )
)
pause
```

Also **Note** I added `echo` to the `xcopy` line to simulate the command, only remove echo to perform the ACTUAL `xcopy` command once you are happy that it will do what you want it to.

But to basically show you how the choice one should work (as per your example):

```
CHOICE /C DEFH /M "Choose driveletter "
if errorlevel 4 set "Drive=H:"
if errorlevel 3 set "Drive=F:"
if errorlevel 2 set "Drive=E:"
if errorlevel 1 set "Drive=D:"
echo xcopy /e /y "G:\2019-Year10\*.*" "%Drive%\"
```

Or to automate it based on your know drive letters, instead of detecting it like the first example (as per your example)

```
@echo off
for %%i in (D: E: F: H:) do (
    if exist %%i echo xcopy /e /y "G:\2019-Year10\*.*" "%%i\"
)
```

Comment: Thanks got it working
What dose %%i mean in the last one?